How can I access a block device file as a regular file with defined size in Linux?
I need to transfer all the data from an external hard drive through the internet, including its partition table, boot sector - everything -, but I don't have space anywhere to copy that entire hard drive into an image file to do that.
Plus, the person to whom I'm transferring is a Windows user, and the way he wants me to transfer, for our ease, is to make a torrent out of it, using Deluge (I'll run it on Wine). This makes things easier as we'll both be able to stop, resume and change networks all we want.
But it can't open a block device file as if it were a normal file, so I need some way to make it accessible like a regular file.
There's the project diskfile, but it doesn't work on my Linux (Mint Tricia 19.3). It compiles and it seemingly runs, but all it does is to mount something in the mountpoint without creating any of the files it should inside it, plus it's 9 years old already.
Is there currently any feasible alternative to do this?
Because for the rest it seems that I'd need to resort to much more difficult alternatives, specially considering he is a windows user and that this upload will take many hours in a way or the other.
And this isn't the first time I'm faced with a similar problem, where I want to access a block device file with software that can only possibly open a regular file, like any software running on Wine.


Even if the other person uses Windows, why do you need to run Deluge on Wine? Is there something specific about it that Deluge on Linux cannot do?


... or any other bittorrent client that can make torrent files, for that matter?

It doesn't actually matter if it's Deluge or not, it was just his suggestion, but no software of this kind, Linux-native or not, can torrent an entire block device like /dev/sdb either. Nor torrent nor upload to a cloud nor anything similar, they can't handle a block device as if it was a regular file, specially because they can't see its size. Opening a block device for reading in a simple program is easy, but these programs expect attributes they won't have.

Which is surprising, given that the whole reason for block devices was that they could be handled as if they were regular files with zero special care from the program. (Like, it's openable and seekable like a regular file – there are no fancy attributes involved.) So that sounds like a deliberate restriction by the programs themselves?

I wouldn't say it's surprising. Has you ever tried to open one with a regular user software? Like trying to  upload a device file on Firefox or Chrome to anywhere. This doesn't work, the upload always fails. They see it as a special, zero-byte file. Software like text editors, image editors, they'll always fail, even if the content on the block device if exactly the content they're expecting, but they can't read it. If you dd that device into a regular file then they can open it.

Perhaps the whole problem is rooted on the fact that the method to get the size (if any) of a block device isn't the same as that of a regular file. Some devices are streams, other have variable sizes, so the device file can't always mirror its size as an attribute that can be read as that of a regular file, although that this can be done for all storage devices at least. Once I mirrored them with bindfs as a regular file with a defined size, regular software seem to be able to open them (as long as they have permission, of course).

Yeah, it's true that they seem to require an ioctl to get their size, but, any device that's a stream or has a variable size wouldn't be a block device – it would be a character device. Block devices are seekable (as part of their purpose), and if a file is seekable then it has to have a definite 'end' to seek to; so they're only used for things that have a fixed size, i.e. only storage.

Then it only makes it less comprehensible for why doesn't Linux makes this by default, make all character device files mirror their size as a regular attribute. I mean, I can see the problems this would cause, from computing the size of directories to having software trying to write after the end of the file as if it were a regular file you could just expand, after all they're not regular files and the software should be aware of that. But it ends up defeating the purpose of this for most user software at least, as they expect only regular files.

bindfs implements a FUSE-based pass-through "filesystem" (mirroring an existing location's contents much like the in-kernel mount --bind does) and has the option --block-devices-as-files to rewrite the file type seen by programs. (There are really no other functional differences except for the 'type' field.)
bindfs --block-devices-as-files /dev /notdev


Thanks, I think this works. Now at least the device file appears as a file with the size of the device. Let's see if regular software like Firefox can try uploading it.

Thanks, it worked! Now I can upload it and open it with most regular software. Perhaps all the problems were caused simply by it's reported zero-byte size.
